# Python timedelta receiving unexpected results

Tags: python, datetime, methods, time, timedelta

In a web application I'm writing for an existing database I need to calculate the difference between now and a timestamp stored in the database (in a text field, it's stupid, I know). Here's my sqlalchemy `Ban` class and the relevant method.

```
class Ban(base):
    __tablename__= 'bans'

    id= Column('banID', Integer, primary_key=True)
    unban_timestamp= Column('UNBAN', Text)
    banned_steamid= Column('ID', Text, ForeignKey('rp_users.steamid'))
    banned_name= Column('NAME', Text)
    banner_steamid= Column('BANNER_STEAMID', Text, ForeignKey('rp_users.steamid'))
    banner_name= Column('BANNER', Text)
    reason= Column('REASON', Text)

    def unbanned_in(self, mode):
        if self.unban_timestamp == '0':
            return 'Never'
        else:
            now= datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            time= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(self.unban_timestamp))
            if now > time:
                return 'Expired'
            else:
                remaining= time - now
                if mode=='readable':
                    return remaining
                elif mode=='int':
                    return str(remaining.seconds).zfill(10)
```

I need both the integer and the pretty string representations because I'll be presenting this in a html table and javascript needs a simple way to sort it. The problem I'm facing is that the integers and strings are not matching up, as you can see in this screenshot here:

[image: example html table]

if anyone can make sense of why the output is so screwed up that would be appreciated! if there's any more information that you need to answer my question I'll gladly add it.

*edit*

for the record at the top of the screenshot the unbanned_in timestamp is `1320247970` if I run that through my function this is the result I get

```
>>> ban = session.query(db.Ban).filter_by(id=3783).one()
>>> print ban.unbanned_in('int'), ban.unbanned_in('readable')
0000049044 2 days, 13:37:24.179045
```

Comment: "so screwed up"?  Please be specific on what -- specifically -- you find "screwed up".  If there's any way to produce a simple text listing of the values (not a screen shot) then that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the number of seconds between `time` and `now`, use

`remaining.days * 24 * 3600 + remaining.seconds`
instead of just `remaining.seconds`

Answer (score 1):

The output is screwed up because your calculation to convert a number of seconds to days, hours, minutes and seconds is wrong. Since you didn't post that bit of code that's all I can say, but note that there are 86400 seconds in a day and all of the counts of seconds you output are smaller than this.

The values you output for hours, minutes and seconds look fine, just your calculation for days is wrong.

Comment: the line `return remaining` is what converts it, that's effectively running `str(datetime.timedelta)`